# How do I pass the Variables from Javascript Url

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a form on filling all the information and it refreshes  and go to the same form .
which needs  2 parametrs  to be passed to  the url . Now my problem is I dont want to show 2 params in the url How can I do that? 
This is the url. 
`$myurl = '/root/subroot/banking.php?a1=test&a2=test2'`

I want to change the URL to 
`$myurl = '/root/subroot/banking.php'`

Can the two parameters also go through without showing in the Url I mean through any other. I created params in this way Would that  help in creatin variables

```
$('#a1').attr('value', 'test');
$('#a2').attr('value', 'test2'). but did not work out
```

Comment: How are you "refreshing" the form? With Ajax or a simple submit button?

Comment: @Drackir:simple Submit button

Comment: Show your form/code that fails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `<form method="get">` to `<form method="post">`

**Edit**
If you don't want `a1` and `a2` to be seen, you can use `<input type="hidden" name="a1" value="test" />` (same for a2). Though, just a note this information is visible in the markup and headers sent to the server so if you're hiding something there that you don't want the user to be able to see, you probably don't want to do it this way.

Comment: @Derby: Do you have this: `action="/root/subroot/banking.php?a1=test&a2=test2"`, if so, remove the query string and see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

On a sidenote, if you're using jQuery, you might wanna use

```
$('#a1').val('test');
```

instead of

```
$('#a1').attr('value', 'test');
```